# Corrupted filesystem - unable to mount /home

Tags: 12.04, mount, filesystem, home-directory, fsck

Ubuntu 12.04 is not able to mount /home partition and I run:

```
fsck /dev/sda5
```

which is in state

```
Pass 1D: Reconciling multiply-claimed blocks
(There are 41608 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)
```

And then it is a question:

```
Clone multiply-claimed blocks<y>?
```

What should I do? Keep pressing Yes it could take weeks till go through all 41608 inodes.
There is some data in the /home partition that I would like to save.
Do I have more options to recover this partition?

Thank you

[EDIT]

Start confirming (by clicking 'y') and on some of them I've got the following:

```
clone_file_block: internal error: can't find dup_blk for 121143344
```

[UPDATE-01]
after David's answer and booting live system image of Ubuntu 14.10-beta Utopic...
and running

```
e2fsck -p /dev/sda5
```

I've got the following:

```
/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda5: Root inode is not a directory. /dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY;
run fsck MANUALLY. (i.e. without -a or -p options)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Advisory note: It would be a very good idea to backup the entire file system before performing any changes or fixes to it.* If you don't have enough space for that use [`e2image(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/e2image.8.html) as an emergency precaution.

### Fixing corrupt superblocks [Edit]

According to your comment you have a corrupt file system superblock. There's an [answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/221179) that deals with this.

Since it's impossible to find the correct block size without a working superblock, I would guess from the volume size of 400 GB that the block size is 4 KiB, which leads to a superblock backup position of 32768. Therefore

```
e2fsck -b 32768 -p /dev/sda5
```

and then take it from there depending on the output.

### Fighting the repetitive user interaction requests

I pulled the following from the [`e2fsck(8)` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/e2fsck.8.html):

> ```
> -p     Automatically  repair  ("preen")  the  file system.  This option
>        will cause e2fsck to automatically fix any  filesystem  problems
>        that  can be safely fixed without human intervention.  If e2fsck
>        discovers a problem which may require the  system  administrator
>        to  take  additional  corrective  action,  e2fsck  will  print a
>        description of the problem  and  then  exit  with  the  value  4
>        logically  or'ed  into  the  exit  code.   (See  the  EXIT  CODE
>        section.)  This option is normally used  by  the  system's  boot
>        scripts.   It may not be specified at the same time as the -n or
>        -y options.
>
> -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
>        used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
>        same time as the -n or -p options.
> ```

The `-p`-option is the safer route in case there are other serious errors, but if that doesn't work, try `-y`.

### `clone_file_block` error

This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/e2fsprogs/+bug/1321418). You can try your luck with a newer version of the `e2fsprogs` packages from the pre-release Utopic series [through Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/e2fsprogs) or [with a live system image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/utopic/).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out with this. Just for clarification - you're suggesting to run fsck or 'e2fsck -p /dev/sda5' , do I understood correctly?

Comment: Just use `e2fsck -p …` in this case. If sda5 contains is an ext file system, `fsck` defers to `e2fsck` – and it definitely does since we wouldn't see that error message otherwise.

Comment: I'm downloading utopic right now and will create live system image, boot and run e2fsck ... the one thing I'm worried is that I don't have additional 400GB hard drive to backup or clone the /home partition. Thanks I will comment when have the result.

Comment: here is what I've got after running 'e2fsck -p /dev/sda5' - /dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced. /dev/sda5: Root inode is not a directory. /dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; run fsck MANUALLY. (i.e. without -a or -p options)

What should I do next?

Comment: Please add this info to your question and see my edit.

Comment: e2fsck with -y option is running now, should I stop it and try with -b (even though I'm not quite sure what to look for) option? And in addition while it is running still on some inodes (or files not sure how to address this) I'm getting clone_file_block errors

Comment: If the superblock is corrupt, all the subsequent data and errors are meaningless because they rely on faulty data. You need to find a working superblock first before fixing any problems.

Comment: wierd, Ctrl+C doesn't interrupt the process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17490/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-venta7).